# form_for was put inside fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a problem with `form_for` and `fields_for`.

So, my problem is:

- I had a `form_for`, and inside this `form_for`, I use a `fields_for`. Inside this `fields_for`, I use a `form_tag` (i used ajax for this `form_tag`).
- But when I view the generated HTML, it didn't display `form_tag`, it only display `form_for`. And I didn't understand why.
- Please explain for me, why it didn't display `form_tag`.

Here is my `form_for`:

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_for @real_estate, url: admin_real_estate_update_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for(:client) do |client| %>
      <%= text_field :real_estate, :assessment_start_at, value: @real_estate.assessment_start_at %>    
      <%= render partial: "admin/real_estate/form/assessment", locals: {real_estate_id: @real_estate.id} %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Submut", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is my `form_for` which i put inside `fields_for`:

```
<%= form_tag admin_search_assessment_path(real_estate_id), method: :post, remote: true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :company_name, params[:company_name] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

And i tried to add `<form></form>` follow as:

```
<div class="row">
  <%= form_for @real_estate, url: admin_real_estate_update_path do |f| %>
    <form></form>
    <%= f.fields_for(:client) do |client| %>
      <%= text_field :real_estate, :assessment_start_at, value: @real_estate.assessment_start_at %>    
      <%= render partial: "admin/real_estate/form/assessment", locals: {real_estate_id: @real_estate.id} %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Submut", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And `form_tag` was display, but `form_for` didn't display.

**Update:**

So, i used `$("form_2").submit(function() {....});` to solve this problem.
Actually, i still want to use form-nested.

Comment: You cannot nest form tags. This is not valid HTML. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the second form (form_tag), i used ajax to submit data. So, do we have other cases to solve this problem ?

Comment: Then you need to make it a separate form, un-nested, with `remote: true`.

Comment: @AmitA Thank for your answer, but follow as my project and my contest, i must work as form nested. So, do you have any advise for me ?

Comment: you cannot do what you are trying to do. It is not valid and the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: You can't nest forms. Instead of having a structure of `<form id="a">...<form id="b">...</form>...</form>` use the structure `<form id="a">...</form>...<form id="b">...</form>`. You may need to duplicate fields, or "pair" fields in form a with hidden fields in form b using Javascript, but that's life. Your only other option is to use Javascript to submit data to the server, e.g. using jQuery's `$.ajax` function when the user performs some behavior. This will require you to write code that compiles the right data to send from the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Inside this `fields_for`, I use a `form_tag` (i used ajax for this `form_tag`)

N'est pas possible, mon ami.

--

Here's how it works...

`form_for` and `form_tag` *both* generate pure HTML forms:

```
<form action="/action" method="POST">
</form>
```

Many people get confused about how Rails works - it's really quite simple. Rails employs ["helper" methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-basic-forms) to generate pure HTML which your browser can read.

Browsers only understand HTML/CSS at the moment. Thus, whenever you send a request to Rails - it *has* to return that data, otherwise a "web page" simply wouldn't be able to be processed.

Thus, when you ask whether you can *nest* forms, you have to abide by how the [forms work in pure HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) ([spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html)):

> Note you are not allowed to nest FORM elements!
>
> HTML fill-out forms can be used for questionaires, hotel reservations,
>   order forms, data entry and a wide variety of other applications. The
>   form is specified as part of an HTML document. The user fills in the
>   form and then submits it. The user agent then sends the form's
>   contents as designated by the FORM element. Typically, this is to an
>   HTTP server, but you can also email form contents for asynchronous
>   processing.

In short, it means that everything *within* a `<form>` tag is counted as a form by HTTP. This means that if you have *another* `<form>` tag, it's going to cause an error, preventing either from working.

---

You know this already (otherwise you wouldn't have mentioned `ajax`).

Your main problem is the use of `<form></form>` inside your current `<form>` object. This will confuse HTML profusely, and thus I would recommend *replicating* the submission of a form, without the `<form>` object itself:

```
#app/views/admin/real_estate/form/assessment.html.erb
<%= text_field_tag "[company_name]", params[:company_name], id: real_estate_id %>
<%= button_tag "Submit", type: "button" , data: { id: real_estate_id } %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "button", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var real_estate_id = $(this).data("id");
   $.ajax({
      url: "path/to/real/estate/form/assessment/" + $(this).data("id")),
      data: {company_name: $("input[type=text]#" + real_estate_id).val()}
      success: function(data) {
         //do something on success
      },
      error: function(data) {
         //do something on error
      }
   });
});
```

This code will still output what you need.

The difference will be two-fold:

> 1. The user will experience the same functionality (the `input` will still be present)
> 2. The embedded form will be passed to the main "form" submit, *but* will not be passed through your strong params method (making it
>      invisible to your controller)

In effect, you're *replicating* the functionality of an HTML form through Ajax. Whilst I still wouldn't do it this way, it will give you the functionality you require.